# Returning a JObject as Json from an endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var taxonomyJson = JObject.FromObject(taxonomy);
return Json(taxonomyJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I've tried converting `taxonomyJson` to a `JToken` and various other properties. I've tried wrapping, etc. But it always throws errors.

Of course, I can return `taxonomyJson.ToString()`, but I don't like that very much because then it wraps an extra double quota around my string which my JavaScript will have to strip off before calling `JSON.parse()` on it.

If `Json()` can handle serializable objects, why can't it handle a `JObject` or a `JToken` that has the JSON already prepared?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about:

```
return Content(taxonomyJson.ToString(), "application/json");
```

And this for an array:

```
var jObject = JObject.FromObject(new { Payload = arrayOfJObjects });
return Content(jObject.ToString(), "application/json");
```

Comment: How about if the payload is a list of JObject items. What is the best way for doing that?

Comment: Worked for me thanks, just a note the return type on the method needs to be ContentResult.

Answer (score 0):

It is really meant to handle the `taxonomy` object you already have, no need to convert it using one Json serializer (Json.NET) to use another (System.Web.Javascript.Serializer) to send it down the wire.

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem I'm facing is that I have two different data structures that I need to merge together. I'm having a hard time doing this with server side objects, so I'm converting them into JObjects and merging them together.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper method to do this server side like

```
public static class JSON{
      public static string ToJavaScriptObject(this object @object){
          var jobject =  JObject.FromObject(@object).ToString();
          jobject = jobject.Substring(1);
          jobject = jobject.Substring(0,jobject.Length-1);
          return jobject;
      }
}
```

Comment: Intereseting idea, but I don't think it would work. The extra quotes don't get attached until later, so this would really just strip off the first and last character of my JSON.

Comment: @Samo, then it sounds like your best bet is a custom ActionResult.  Check out this blog post, it might have what you need : http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx